# Undefined control sequence \ProvidesPackageRCS

Tags: beamer

[image]

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.11 \ProvidesPackageRCS
                         $Header: /Users/Joseph/Documents/LaTeX/beamer/base/...
```

I'm getting this problem during compilation. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

There may be other local versions of `beamer`-related content in your folder. This was only the first one identified during compilation.

Delete `beamerbasemodes.sty` from your working folder (`D:\Geet D1ppt`) and re-compile. If errors continue, it probably means that you've installed an older version of `beamer` to your working folder. Remove that local installation and use the MiKTeX Package Manager (MPM) to install the appropriate versions/updates to `beamer` instead.